# Not able to connect to a service based in kubernetes using lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this function in lisp with which i am trying to access a service based in kubernetes in the intranet, but i am not able to connect to the service.Using curl command to access the service url works fine.

```
(defun call-service (host port request-msg timeout ssl-val)
   (declare (special *debug-level-2* *debug-level-3*))
   (let ((http-stream nil)
         (rtn-msg nil)
        )
      (when (and host port request-msg timeout)
         (setf http-stream (comm:open-tcp-stream host port :ssl-ctx ssl-val
                                         :direction :io
                                         :read-timeout timeout
                                         :write-timeout 3
                                         :timeout 3))
         (if (streamp http-stream)
            (handler-case
               (unwind-protect
                  (progn
                     (debugger *debug-level-3*  "Calling Service: " request-msg)
                     (format http-stream "~a~c~c~c~c" request-msg
                                         (code-char 13) (code-char 10)
                                         (code-char 13) (code-char 10))
                     (force-output http-stream)
                     (do ((line t))
                          ((unless line))
                        (setq line (read-line http-stream nil nil))
                        (setq rtn-msg (concatenate 'simple-string
                              (when rtn-msg rtn-msg) (when rtn-msg "
") line))
                        (when (or (not line)
                                  (equal line "")
                                  (equal (subseq line 0 1) "0")
                                  (equal (subseq line 0 1) "}"))
                           (return)))
                     (close http-stream)))
               (error (condition)
                  (debugger *debug-level-1* 1710 host
                                                       "Service Not Available"
                     (format nil "~a" condition)))
               (:no-error (value)
                  (debugger *debug-level-3* "Return from Web Service:" rtn-msg)))
            (debugger *debug-level-1* 1700
                      "Service " host port
                      "CANNOT BE OPENED")))
      rtn-msg))
```

The service is something like this:

[http://xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx.xxxxxxx-xxxx.xxxx.intranet/v1/qualification](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

For the http-stream i am getting this:

```
(setf http-stream (comm:open-tcp-stream host port :ssl-ctx ssl-val
                                         :direction :io
                                         :read-timeout timeout
                                         :write-timeout 3
                                         :timeout 3))
NIL
```

But for the other service which is not based in kubernetes, i am getting this:

```
(setf http-stream (comm:open-tcp-stream host port :ssl-ctx ssl-val
                                         :direction :io
                                         :read-timeout timeout
                                         :write-timeout 3
                                         :timeout 3))
#<COMM:SOCKET-STREAM 4010016E8B>
```

Want to connect to the service which is based in kubernetes, this service provides the response when i try the curl command.

Comment: by default when it returns NIL there's a secondary return value (discarded by setq) that contains an error object. Alternatively you can pass :errorp t to enter the debugger in case of error. This should give a bit more information

Comment: Thank you, i am able to connect to the service now